# Is this a serial LCD?

Tags: lcd, raspberry-pi

I had a broken remote for a small RC helicopter that I took the LCD off.

I dont know the size, but I could try to describe the pins and maybe someone could pinpoint what this is.

It has 7 pins, and from the top it is labeled:

- BZB (not used)
- BZ (not used)
- VDD
- GND
- DATA
- WR
- CS
- LED-
- LED+

Just a serial screen? And what are the WR/CS/LED-/+ pins? Thought I could try to hook it up to my Raspberry PI laters if possible.

Comment: what is the original chip that LCD was connected to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like it:

DATA is probably your input serial data line

WR is probably a write enable

CS seems like a chip select for the control to me

LED- and LED+ are the power and gnd for the backlight

Oh and since there's no clock signal it's probably a uart interface like a RS232 (probably not at RS232 voltage levels though).  Maybe try that first messing around with the baud rate until you get some garbage or a character to show up.  There's probably also single character commands to clear the LCD which you can figure out by trying.  Like sending 0x01 clear or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a Serial LCD, yes.

For the pinout, this is not absolutely certain, but:

DATA = Data In
WR = Write data strobe (i.e. data clock in)
CS = Chip Select - hold either high/low (depending on logic polarity) to enable.
LED + = Backlight LED anode
LED - = Backlight LED cathode

Comment: WR often uses negative logic, i.e. low = write strobe

Answer (score 1):

This is the data sheet of the circuit that controller the display.

https://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/950456/ETC2/N79E814AS20/8156/77/N79E814AS20.html

pin1 is CS
pin2 is Clock
pin3 is Data

Is a Microcontroller, but I do not know,
how to program it.

in the microcontroller

Pin 1 is SPICLK, KB0, PWM3, 00.0
Pin 2 is ICPCLK, MOSI, PWM2, P1.7
Pin 3 is ICPDATA, MISO, PWM1, P1.6

Comment: You posted a question as an answer to an existing question. This is not how this site works. Please ask a new question by using the button **Ask Question** in the top right corner.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same LCD, while not being able to get it working with an arduino, i found that the controller sends a clock like (High, Low, High, Low etc..) signal to both the WR and CS pins. I got this from loading the analog read serial sketch to my arduino and then probing the pins. With help from the sketch of greynomad [Click Here](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=38160.0)  i found that the controller sends signals at 115200 Baud. Hope this helps!